# c - how to split double multiplication?

Tags: c, double, precision

I'm using avr-gcc where `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(float)` are both `4` and I'm having an issue with double arithmetic to get the correct integer result:

```
// x is some value between 8.0 and 9.6103
double x = 9.6103;
uint32_t r = pow(x,2) * 8813377.768984962;
```

The correct value of r should be `813984763` rounded down but the actual result is `813984768`.
How can I get the correct integer result?

I've tried to split the calculation like this:

```
uint32_t r1 = pow(x,2) * 8813;
double d1 = pow(x,2) * .77768984962;
uint32_t r = r1 + d1;
```

But this still suffers from precision issues i.e I can't seem to get `813984763` exactly and I'm only interested in that the integer part of the result is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: As a general rule, don't use `pow()` for small integer powers.  Use ordinary multiplication instead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This was just a snippet of part of the calculation but I am using the power up to 7. Should `pow` still not be used in that case?

Comment: Did you consider using integer (for example `long long`) calculations _only_? What are you calculating? Can the input value be an integer?

Comment: @KamilCuk Your previous comment mentioned something about integer arithemetic only? Does that mean that the whole calculation (pow()  and multiplication) has to be done using integers only for this to work? The input cannot be an integer. I'm calculating a polynomial fit of order 7 for a curve.

Comment: You are using `avr-gcc` - does your platform has hardware floating-point support? Otherwise simple `pow` is _a lot_ of code. And - did you consider just `long double` it?

Comment: @KamilCuk No FPU sadly, the code size increase when using 7 `pow` calls is quite neglible on my platform (0.7% increase in program size)

Comment: `double x = 9.6103; __uint128_t y = x * 10000; uint32_t r = y * y * 881337776898 / 10000/10000 /100000; printf("%u\n", r);` seems to work fine - you could also write or use a library that implements `uint128_t` operations.

Comment: @KamilCuk it is 8 bits architecture and every float operation is > 1000clocks. There was not duoble suppeor till v10 because double operations will consume tens of thousand clocs.

Comment: Best practice - forget about floats. Do all operations on integers.

Comment: Re “x is some value between 8.0 and 9.6103”: In what form do you have `x`? If you have it as a `float` (or a `double` that is the same as `float` in that system), then you have already lost too much information to compute the desired result even if you use infinitely precise arithmetic. The IEEE-754 binary32 (a.k.a single or `float`) value closest to 9.6103 is 9.6103000640869140625. When you square that and multiply by 8813377.768984962, using exact real arithmetic, the result is about 813984774.6447, so rounding down to an integer yields 813984774, off by 11 from the desired 813984763.

Comment: If you have `x` in some other form and it is exact, or at least sufficiently precise, then the computation should be possible, but you will have to use some form of extended precision arithmetic, in either floating-point or integer. Or do you have `x` in the `float` format but know the ideal *x* is a number with four decimal digits after the decimal point, so we can recover it from `x` by rounding to a decimal numeral?

Answer (score 1):

A `float` cannot represent the precision you need for this *value* (813984763), much less for the calculation, and as you've noted `avr-gcc` has wrongly redefined `double` to be the same as `float`.

The closest representable values in `float` are:

- Below: 813984704
- Above: 813984768 (closer)

Comment: Would you mind saving me a trip to the standard by explaining why it is wrong for `double` to have the same properties as `float`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Annex F specifies that `double` is IEEE double precision. While strictly speaking Annex F is an optional part of the standard, the base standard is sufficiently under-specified on the semantics of everything floating point that it's impossible to do anything writing floating point code to just the base standard without Annex F.

Comment: Not exactly.  Annex F specifies that only for implementations that define macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`, and even implementations that generally conform to IEEE / IEC arithmetic and formats have the option to avoid defining that macro in order to avoid being bound by Annex F.  (So much for avoiding a trip to the standard.)

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE So will I have to implement the whole calculation using integers only?

Comment: “A `float` cannot represent the precision you need…” is not an answer to the question OP asks, which is “How can I get the correct integer result?”, not “How can I get the correct integer result using `float`?”

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That's exactly what I meant by it being "optional" and my point about implementations that don't follow it being useless for floating point stands.

Answer (score 0):

You could scale it up and use 128-bit integers to do the arithmetic. 128-bit is soooo much you could just multiply it all to integers.

```
double x = 9.6103;
uint128_t y = x * 10000; // = 96103 / 10000
uint128_t c = 8813377768984962; // = 8813377.768984962 * 1000000000
uint32_t r = y * y * c / 10000/10000 /1000000000;
// max y * y * c = 96103 * 96103 * 8813377768984962 =
//             = 81398476378849607561973858
// UINT128_MAX = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
// ^^ is way more, so it will not overflow.
```

Your platform most probably does not support `__uint128_t` GCC extension, so you could write your own library for that. There are *endless* 128-bit libraries in C++ on github - port one to C (or find one in C) and use it.

---

Well, I got some free time and I always wanted to have a C uint128 library, so I took this library https://github.com/calccrypto/uint128_t and [ported it to C](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/-/blob/master/libs/kuint128/src/kuint128.c) and wrote an executable that does the same computations as presented above and compiled it for atmega128 with `avr-gcc -Os` and run `avr-nm -td --sort-size` over the result. These are the biggest 5 symbols in the result and the whole program has ~12KB of `.text`. So, a bit of space is needed for this solution to work.

```
00000642 T how_to_split_double_multiplication
00000706 T kuint128_rshift
00000762 T kuint128_lshift
00003104 T kuint128_mul
00004594 T kuint128_divmod
```

Comment: This is not a solution for a microcontroller with a few tens or at most a couple hundred kB of code space.

Comment: Is not? https://github.com/calccrypto/uint128_t/blob/master/uint128_t.cpp#L338 - does not seem _that_ much of code space. I have no better idea how do it and stay in `uint64_t` range, so while it's not "perfect" solution, it will work and seems doable. Why do you think it's not a solution for such microcontroller? Does uint128_t library take that much codespace?